PySide6 QSortFilterProxyModel filter proxy removes peristent editor
I have a QTableView containing a column with checkboxes. I use a delegate for the checkbox because I want to align it in the center of the column. The one which is generated via the CheckStateRole isn't. The checkbox editor is made permanent for this column.
To sort and filter the table I use a QSortFilterProxyModel. Sorting works and filtering with wildcards also. But if I remove the wildcard filter, the checkboxes of the formerly filtered rows are not drawn. Instead the column shows 0 or 1.
The code is:
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, Property, Signal, QAbstractTableModel
from PySide6.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel, QSignalBlocker
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QCheckBox, QHBoxLayout, QStyledItemDelegate,
                               QTableView, QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow,
                               QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QFrame)


class CenterCheckBox(QWidget):
    toggled = Signal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.check = QCheckBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.check, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.check.setFocusProxy(self)
        self.check.toggled.connect(self.toggled)
        # set a 0 spacing to avoid an empty margin due to the missing text
        self.check.setStyleSheet('color: red; spacing: 0px;')
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

    @Property(bool, user=True)   # note the user property parameter
    def checkState(self):
        return self.check.isChecked()

    @checkState.setter
    def checkState(self, state):
        with QSignalBlocker(self.check) as blocker:
            self.check.setChecked(state)


class MyCheckboxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        check = CenterCheckBox(parent)
        check.toggled.connect(lambda: self.commitData.emit(check))
        return check

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.checkState)


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        print(data)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
                if self._data.columns[index.column()]=='Delete':
                    return ''
                value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
                return str(value)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.table_view = QTableView(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.table_view)

        table_model = TableModel(pd.DataFrame([['1', '1'],
                                               ['0', '0'],
                                               ['2', '0']]))
        proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(table_model)
        self.table_view.setModel(proxy_model)
        self.table_view.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(proxy_model.setFilterWildcard)

        self.table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, MyCheckboxDelegate(self))
        for row in range(0, proxy_model.rowCount()):
            self.table_view.openPersistentEditor(proxy_model.index(row, 1))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())


I already searched in internet for such a behaviour, but nothing found. What I can do to see the checkboxes again after clearing the wildcard filter? May be to call openPersistentEditor again, but how to know when?
BTW:
Is there a description of the interaction between delegates, views, models and so on?
Until now I only found documentation about the classes and a very basic description
of the model view architecture.

First of all, I strongly suggest you to carefully read the whole Model/View Programming Guide.
When using proxy models, any filter change will result in possibly invalidating current indexes whenever they are removed.
Your first call to openPersistentEditor() will create editors for existing indexes, but altering the filter of the proxy will also result in destroying those indexes, which will automatically delete their related editors.
When the filter is changed (possibly "unfiltering" previously hidden indexes), new indexes will be shown. It doesn't matter that they virtually existed before that: to the QTableView's point of view they are new indexes, which means that new persistent editors must be created for them.
A possible solution, then, is to do what you already do within initialization, which is to call openPersistentEditor() for any new index. If you think about it, it makes sense: you're opening editors that didn't exist before, so you shall do the same whenever a "new" index is being shown (aka, restored by the filter).
This is easily achieved by connecting to the QAbstractItemModel rowsInserted signal.
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # you should really use super!!!
        super().__init__(*args)
        ...
        proxy_model.rowsInserted.connect(self.updateEditors)

    def updateEditors(self):
        model = self.table_view.model()
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            index = model.index(row, 1)
            if not self.table_view.isPersistentEditorOpen(index):
                self.table_view.openPersistentEditor(index)

Note that a more appropriate and dynamical solution should use a QTableView subclass, which will:

set the delegate on its own;
implement a similar updateEditors() method;
override setModel(), possibly disconnect the rowsInserted signal if a previous model existed, call the default implementation, and eventually connect the signal of the new model (if it exists) to the related method/slot;

While the above may result more complex, its benefit is that it will always work consistently, no matter if you're using the source mode, a proxy, or even a nested proxy.

Thank you. I will try it tomorrow. I already read the recommended guide, but I haven't found that the proxy model also changes the indexes of its source model. I thought that these indexes are only changed if the models data is changed.

It seems that for sorting the indexes aren't changed. So I thought filtering works too.

@GePe The whole concept of a proxy is that it acts as its source, possibly completely hiding it and altering its behavior. As far as the view knows, there is only one model. When using sorting, the index ordering is changed, but the length isn't. If you filter the source, the proxy will fundamentally remove an index, therefore shifting any following ones. Consider the model as an array of pointers: altering the order of those pointers doesn't change the size of the array. Filtering does change the size, meaning that unfiltering introduces new indexes.

I know the concept of a proxy. But knowing it doesn't explain which behaviour is altered.

For me there is no big difference between sorting and filtering. Sorting generates a translation table for rows. So after sorting you have to give the view for row 1 another row ([b, a] => [a, b]). Filtering does nearly the same, the only difference is that the translation table is shorter than the number of data rows ([b, a] => [a]). This can be done by manipulating the row count for the view. There is no need for new indexes. But I found no description how the proxy works, so I assumed both do the same.

Now I use your first solution. To use the subclass I have to change the auto generated ui (no good idea), or add the new class to the designer (don't know how).

@GePe The proxy model exposes its own indexes. As said, the view only knows about its own model and its indexes, it doesn't care (nor should) about the possible underlying data structure. To the point of view of the item view, a model that is being filtered is exactly the same as removing a row (or column), therefore "restoring" (by unfiltering) is exactly the same as creating a new row/column. So, there IS need for new indexes, since that's what "unfiltered" indexes are. To clarify, consider the case of a model that is being filtered before being set on the view: for the view »

@GePe » the model only contains a row count consistent with its filtering (eg. 5 rows instead of 8). Now, suppose that you programmatically unset the proxy filter after setting the model: for the view, the model has changed its row count, it didn't know anything about the "unfiltered state". That's why new indexes are being created (that's the purpose of rowsInserted signals), and it's the reason for which your code didn't work. You're right about not editing UI files, but you don't need to do that if you want to use subclasses: do some research about promoted widgets instead.

So the proxy has indexes to talk with the view and others to talk with the model? This means it does some translation. Why it can't do the same for the row count? The model uses signals to stay informed if data changes. So the proxy also knows about this and can update the view if by applying the filter or the sort to the new data. If I call insertRows via the proxy it also translates the indexes.

By changing the filter, the data model is not changed by the proxy, you can't delete data by filtering the view of them. So the models row count stays the same and if you remove the filter the proxy sends the models row count to the view and not the filtered row count. So there is no need to destroy the indexes for the data model. And if the persistent editor is connected to the index of the data model it will stay active.

@GePe No. It doesn't work like that. The proxy doesn't alter the source data (or indexes). It has its own indexes*, which will eventually be "translated" to the source data using its internal mapping. In fact, a basic Qt item model could filter its own contents just by removing or creating new indexes. It seems you're a bit confused about how data models work in general, and how they're implemented in Qt. I strongly suggest you to take your time and carefully study related materials, including the official Qt Model/View Programming Guide.
